# how to customize autocomplete TO field in privatemsg module - drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Using the privatemessage module, users can send messages to each other as in facebook. The page displays a form with a TO field, subject and message. The TO field is an autocomplete field by default. Upon searching for a user name, it shows a drop down with only the names. How can i customize it to show the user's profile picture also in the drop down??? I dont know where to go and make the code changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have better luck with this on Drupal StackExchange, where the co-maintainer of Privatemsg is very active. (He hasn't posted here in a year, I think.)